# Drupal 7 page template for right to left languages e.g. page--rtl.tpl.php

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n, 7

Trying to create a custom page.tpl dependant on language or 'right to left' support, here is what i have so far.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if($variables['language']->language == 'ar') {
      $variables['template_file'] = 'page--ar';
    }
}
```

Am i on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 7, what you'll want to do is something along these lines:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if($variables['language']->language == 'ar') {
     $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__ar';
  }
}
```

which will cause Drupal to look for a `page--ar.tpl.php` file (or even a `THEMENAME__page__ar()` function, which is the reason for the underscores in the variable value btw) when `$language` is set to `ar`.

A possible enhancement:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if(isset($variables['language'])) {
     $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $variables['language']->language;
  }
}
```

will cause Drupal to look for `page--XX.tpl.php` files and will use them if they exist; otherwise, will just keep looking for a less specific template and will end up using `page.tpl.php`.  This way, you don't have to have a lot `if's` in your preprocess logic.

For that matter, you can also do something like this:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if(isset($variables['language']) && $variables['language']->dir=='rtl') {
     $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__rtl';
  }
}
```

and now you would have one `page--rtl.tpl.php` file for all `rtl` languages.

Lots of possibilities abound here, a quick:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($variables['language'], TRUE) . '</pre>');
```

in the beginning of your preprocess function will show you what you have to work with.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much. I went with the rtl support version